# Ng-model not working in android or ios but works just fine in ionic serve with no error

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using ng-model to take is a string value and to output another to the a text area. Everything works fine in ionic serve in chrome with no error. When I build for ios or android there are no errors and both build successfully, but when I emulate it there is no output and the ng-model is not filling the text area. I can't figure out what the issue is any suggestions?

I am trying to run the following code. I allow the user to input a string SQL statement the use db.exec() to obtain the results. This works perfectly when I do ionic sever the result gets output to the screen. It does not work when emulated in either ios or android

```
<input type='text' ng-model="sql"></input>

<button ng-click="clickHandler(sql)"; class="button button-positive" id="execute">
        Execute
</button>

<h3>SQL Results</h3>
        <div class="card">
        <div class="item item-text-wrap">
            {{value}}
        </div>
    </div>



 $scope.clickHandler = function(model) {
    console.log(model);
    try {
        db.run(model);// Run the query without returning anything
        console.log('The db.run test successfully read from file')
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("error at db.run initial:  " + err);
    }
    console.log('I have made it to this point');

    $scope.value = db.exec(model);
}
```

Comment: please post your code for "db"

Comment: I figured out the issue. When you retrieve the database from file it works fine in ionic serve because the file path to the database is fine, but when you ionic emulate ios the location to the file is slightly different and I had change the directory to accommodate for the change. In my case I ../db/file.sqlite  ->  ../www/db/file.sqlite.  I used the debugger in safari to debug the emulator and the main error was that the file could not be found.